# .NET Core 2.2 Checking if Database Exists

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to programmatically check if a database exists. This is how I check it.

The connection string that I pass to it is:

> "Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=org-LocalDBONE-f2d73714-3373-4324-9b0a-c5234baf89be;Trusted_Connection=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User
>   Id=UserOne;Password=P@@123455P"

```
private static async Task<bool> VerifyDatabase(string ConnectionString, string DatabaseName)
{
    using(var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT db_id(@databaseName", connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("databaseName", DatabaseName));
            connection.Open();
            return (await command.ExecuteScalarAsync() != DBNull.Value);
        }

    }
}
```

The problem I am facing now is that when I go through this code, I get this error:

> Message = "Cannot open database
>   \"org-LocalDBONE-f2d73714-3373-4324-9b0a-c5234baf89be\" requested by the
>   login. The login failed.\r\nLogin failed for user
>   'MicrosoftAccount\jonathan.kj@gmail.com'."

How do I use the account in the connection string instead of this Microsoft account?

Also, is it possible to create a user for the database using code instead of going into SQL Management Studio and creating it manually?

EDIT: As suggested by dvitel, I added Integrated Security=false and it uses my username now. However, I get this error now:

> Message = "One or more errors occurred. (Cannot open database
>   \"org-LocalDBONE-f2d73714-3373-4324-9b0a-c5234baf89be\" requested by
>   the login. The login failed.\r\nLogin failed for user 'UserOne'.)"

This is strange because I already use this login to manually perform migrations to this server.

Comment: You're using SQL Server, right?

Comment: Yup! MSSQL Server

Comment: Whats worry me is "SELECT db_id(@databaseName" you forgot )

Comment: Try Integrated Security=false in connection string

Comment: Sorry, I fixed that part. @VolodymyrBilyachat

Comment: I managed to change it with Integrated Security=false but its saying that the Login failed for the user I put in. Its already being used for another database in the same server though

Comment: Update your question with latest error

Comment: Hi @VolodymyrBilyachat I have updated my question.

Comment: You created login on server level, but on db level you should create user and associate it to login. I assume you do not have user in this db? Check CREATE USER FOR LOGIN T-SQL

Comment: @dvitel sorry what does that mean? This login is already being used for other databases on the server. My intention is to check if the database exists and if it doesn't create one with these credentials.

Comment: You said that connection failed. It could be possible because user is not created in current db as you state above https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: The user exists but the database doesn't. My intention is to check if the database exists. If it doesn't I should create one and perform a migration all from code. Would that be possible?

Comment: Remove the `Database=org-LocalDBONE...` from your conenctionstring. Use a connectionstring with database name set to master for checking if database exists.

Comment: @MatJ your solution solved the problem with the login. Could you put it as an answer? Also, can I also create a database user using this method and link it to a created database?

Comment: @JianYA, About user creation, yes [you can](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96358/how-can-i-map-a-login-to-a-database-using-t-sql-not-ssms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if database exists, you should not mention the non existing database in the connection string. All such checks are done against master database anyways, so change the connection string to point to master database.

For Ex:

```
Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=master;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User Id=UserOne;...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you help me understand why the master is used as a comparison? Does it keep track of all the tables that exist on that server?

Comment: Yes, it contains all data about [other databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/master-database?view=sql-server-2017).